# Codeigniter RESTful API - How to use it correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

I have an Application where I use Codeigniter as backend and BackboneJS as frontend.
So I have installed the RESTful server from Phil Sturgeon so I can pass data from my Backend as APIs to my Frontend.

So far it works good but only when I have a small `LIMIT 0,50`  statement.
When I remove the `LIMIT` the amount of Data is high and the GET method truncates data which is over the `LIMIT` so I normally have to use POST method.
So I wonder if my way to use it is correct or wrong.
Like in the documentation i created an `api` folder in `application/controllers/api`.

So one of my APIs looks like this:

```
<?php

require(APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class artistchannel extends REST_Controller{


    public function artistname_get($artist_id)  
    { 
          $this->load->database();
          $sql = "SELECT formated_name FROM artists WHERE artist_id = '".$artist_id."'";
          $query = $this->db->query($sql);
          $data = $query->result();

          if($data) {
            $this->response($data, 200); // 
          } else {
            $this->response(array('error' => 'Couldn\'t find any artist with that name!'), 404);
          }
    }
}

?>
```

Is this a correct way to use it? I have the impression something is wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using, RESTful server from Phil Sturgeon, I would recommend you to take a look into [Guzzle](https://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which have much wider functionality.

Instead of making plain queries to database from controller, I would use models and Active Record instead:

In your `Controller`:

```
public function artistname_get($artist_id)  
{
   $data = $this->ArtistModel->get($artist_id);
   if($data) {
     $this->response($data, 200); // 
   } else {
     $this->response(array('error' => 'Couldn\'t find any artist with that name!'), 404);
   }
}
```

Then perform query in your `ArtistModel`, using Codeigniter [ActiveRecord](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html).
In your `ArtistModel`:

```
public function get($id) 
{
  return $this->db->get_where('artists', array('artist_id' => $id))->row(); 
}
```